# open file select dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have hidden input type=file field, and i want to open its select dialog with javascript. I tried to fire click event on this element, but without luck.

Im using mootools.

```
$('input_id').fireEvent('click');
```

This is possible at all?